# What is dynamic pulse-width modulation?

Tags: modulation, c

I'm working through exercises in a book called *The Audio Programming Book* and have been doing okay for nearly 300 pages, but have just got stuck. (I'm a musician, not programmer or audio specialist BTW, so sorry if this is a dumb question…)

I understand what pulse-width modulation is, and I've managed to write some C code to apply it to a square-wave. The book suggests using a function prototype that includes a frequency parameter; I assumed this would be the same as the frequency of the square-wave. But now I'm thinking that this frequency parameter may be for a LFO that constantly changes the level of pulse-width modulation. **Does dynamic pulse-width modulation suggest a constantly changing level of pulse-width modulation, governed by a LFO?** The next exercise in the book asks for "breakpoint" control over this function - but the values put into this would be dependent upon whether the frequency of pulse-width modulation change is changing, or just pulse-width modulation is changing.

I suspect I may have coded so far for *static* pulse-width modulation of a square wave.

**EDIT:** here's some code…

The following struct holds oscillator information, it is from code in the book (although I added curPWMod):

```
typedef struct t_oscil
{
    double twoPiOvrSR;
    double curFreq;
    double curPWMod;
    double curPhase;
    double incr;
} OSCIL;
```

The following macro updates values if the frequency value passed into functions changes (I wrote this as an exercise from the book, originally code for this was in every function):

```
#define UPDATE_FREQ \
        if (p_osc->curFreq != freq) \
            do { \
                p_osc->curFreq = freq; \
                p_osc->incr = p_osc->twoPiOvrSR * freq; \
            } while (0)
```

The following function is from the book, used to create values for a square wave (originally values set were 1.0, I changed to 0.99 as my audio files were clipping):

```
double squareTick(OSCIL *p_osc, double freq)
{
    double val;
    UPDATE_FREQ;
    if (p_osc->curPhase <= M_PI) {
        val = 0.99; // to avoid clipping
    } else {
        val = -0.99; // to avoid clipping
    }
    p_osc->curPhase += p_osc->incr;
    if (p_osc->curPhase >= TWO_PI) {
        p_osc->curPhase -= TWO_PI;
    }
    if (p_osc->curPhase < 0.0) {
        p_osc->curPhase += TWO_PI;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Here is my similar function to return values for a pulse-width modulated square wave (the constant value of 0.02 is used, because a pwMod value of 50 should give a square-wave):

```
// the next function is for pulse-width-modulated square wave
double pwmTick(OSCIL *p_osc, double freq, double pwMod)
{
    // this should BASICALLY be the same as the square wave function, but adjusting for the pwMod input
    double val;
    UPDATE_FREQ;
    if (p_osc->curPWMod != pwMod) {
        p_osc->curPWMod = pwMod;
        if (p_osc->curPWMod < 1.0) {
            p_osc->curPWMod = 1.0;
        }
        if (p_osc->curPWMod > 99.0) {
            p_osc->curPWMod = 99.0;
        }
    } // only changed if pwMod value has changed

    if (p_osc->curPhase <= (M_PI * p_osc->curPWMod * 0.02)) {
        val = 0.99; // to avoid clipping
    } else {
        val = -0.99;
    }

    // the next 7 lines are the same in every function - so should probably be replaced with a macro
    p_osc->curPhase += p_osc->incr;
    if (p_osc->curPhase >= TWO_PI) {
        p_osc->curPhase -= TWO_PI;
    }
    if (p_osc->curPhase < 0.0) {
        p_osc->curPhase += TWO_PI;
    }

    return val;
}
```

This function does exactly what I expected, but I have no idea if this is what the exercise in the book is asking me to do! Is this **dynamic pulse-width modulation**? My solution uses a different oscillator (and oscillator function), rather than applying another oscillator (sine?) and oscillator function to the pwMod argument passed into this function (which I suspect I'm supposed to do…)

**This book doesn't mention pulse-width modulation before this point, and then gives no explanation of what it is; I don't mind this, it requires the reader to find information themselves, but it is hard work!** The only clue given by the book, as to what this exercise requires, is the given function prototype:

```
double pwmtick(OSCIL* p_osc, double freq, double pwmod);
```

As I say above, I've managed to write a function using this prototype, but am now not sure if the freq parameter refers to the same frequency as in the square-wave function above (which is how I've interpreted it), or if it should be interpreted as a frequency for changing the amount of pwMod applied...

Comment: I think we need a little more information here. What is this function whose parameter is supposed to be a frequency?

Comment: Hi @Phonon, I added loads of extra info and code. I'm now thinking I have followed the right process, and any periodic  change to the pwMod value passed in would itself be produced by another oscillator function first...